# Does anyone know how await publish () works for a Discord bot? In the official manual, I never found a specific announcement

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot make an announcement to a certain channel, based on the Channel ID. But in different manuals I find only `await publish ()` and no comments how does it works and what is for discord.py an announcement channel. The problem is also that I need to shove in one command sending text to the channel where the command comes from and to another channel at the same time.

Instead of the last line, there should be a command that sends a specific message, preferably `Embed` to another channel whose ID I will indicate.

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def new_deposit( ctx, opID: str = None, stID: str = None, fname: str = None, lname: str = None, deposit: str = None):
    insert1 = (opID, stID, fname, lname, deposit)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO depositors( operationID, staticID, fname, lname, deposit) 
        VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""", insert1)
    conn.commit()
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Операция выполнена!')
    emb.add_field( name = 'ID операции', value = '{}'.format( opID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Статический ID', value = '{}'.format( stID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Сумма', value = '{}'.format( deposit ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Имя', value = '{}'.format( fname ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Фамилия', value = '{}'.format( lname ))
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)
    await ctx.publish( title = 'Операция выполнена!')
```

Edited:
Ok, got it, announcement channels can create only servers with enabled Community func.
Then another question, how I can do this without an announcement channel?

Edited: I'm add it like that:

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def new_deposit( ctx, opID: str = None, stID: str = None, fname: str = None, lname: str = None, deposit: str = None):
    insert1 = (opID, stID, fname, lname, deposit)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO depositors( operationID, staticID, fname, lname, deposit) 
        VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""", insert1)
    conn.commit()
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Операция выполнена!')
    emb.add_field( name = 'ID операции', value = '{}'.format( opID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Статический ID', value = '{}'.format( stID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Сумма', value = '{}'.format( deposit ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Имя', value = '{}'.format( fname ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Фамилия', value = '{}'.format( lname ))
    guild = client.get_guild('*************************')
    channel = guild.get_channel('***********************')
    await ctx.send( embed = emb)
    await channel.send( title = 'Операция выполнена!')
```

And what i get it:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'`

Comment: Apologies, as this may be a lack of distinct familiarity with conventions specifically relating to discord.py, but do you mind elaborating on what `ctx` is and how it gets set? What type of object is `ctx`?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=publish#discord.Message.publish) and [this Discord article](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032008192-Announcement-Channels-#:~:text=%F0%9F%8E%89%20Anytime%20you%20post%20an,who%20follow%20your%20Announcement%20Channel) on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the channel object and send using `await channel.send('xyz')` you ofc need the guild obj to get the channel. The code below should work.

```py
@client.command( pass_context = True )
async def new_deposit( ctx, opID: str = None, stID: str = None, fname: str = None, lname: str = None, deposit: str = None):
    insert1 = (opID, stID, fname, lname, deposit)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO depositors( operationID, staticID, fname, lname, deposit) 
        VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""", insert1)
    conn.commit()
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Операция выполнена!')
    emb.add_field( name = 'ID операции', value = '{}'.format( opID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Статический ID', value = '{}'.format( stID ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Сумма', value = '{}'.format( deposit ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Имя', value = '{}'.format( fname ))
    emb.add_field( name = 'Фамилия', value = '{}'.format( lname ))
    guild = client.get_guild('YOUR SERVER ID')
    channel = guild.get_channel('YOUR CHANNEL ID')
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
```